# How do I align my logo and my text in the same class?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to get my text aligned with my logo in my header.

HTML:

```
<div class="haut" style="height:70px">
    <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}" id="logo"><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://i.imgur.com/h6v1Xsm.png" /></i></i> PogWare</a>
    <span class="useroptions">
        <ul id="menu-deroulant">
            <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/memberlist.php">Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/showteam.php">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/misc.php?action=help">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/search.php">Search</a></li>
            {$welcomeblock}
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>>
```

and I got this CSS:

```
#logo {
    color: #cc2e2e;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: 'myfont';
    font-size: 27px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your HTML and CSS is incomplete. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Id

```css
#logo {
    img {
        vertical-align:middle
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}" id="logo"><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://i.imgur.com/h6v1Xsm.png" /> PogWare</a>
```